# Javascript | passing string variable to onclick event not working

Tags: javascript, string, variables, onclick, popup

I am trying to open a popup windows but the button's onclick content is stored in a variable. Thsi is my approach:

```
var page = 'window.open(\'ticket.html?wallet='+global_wallet+'\',\'popUpWindow\');';
document.getElementById('EditButton').onclick=page;
```

This is not working. Not popup being  displayed. Something is missing and i don't figure out what is it...

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `onclick` property is supposed to be a JavaScript function, not a string like you are trying.

You can pass a function:

```
document.getElementById('EditButton').onclick = function(){
    window.open('ticket.html?wallet='+global_wallet,'popUpWindow');
};
```

Or if for some reason you have to use the string, you can set the onclick attribute. In this case you need to use `setAttibute()` instead of the `onclick` property.

```
document.getElementById('EditButton').setAttribute('onclick', page);
```